# Binding caps-lock to a range of commands

Tags: shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout

I never use caps lock, so I'd like to use it as an addition custom modifier key. What modifier keys are there? Super, meta, hyper?

Could I turn the caps lock key into say "hyper" and then assign commands to hyper-a, hyper-b etc? How would I do that?

I'm thinking mainly of commands like beginning of line, end of line etc. Where would those commands (that are currently found to other legal so I can assign them?

Comment: What program are you thinking of using the hyper shortcuts in? Gnome, Gnome Terminal, vim, ...?

Comment: Fwiw I have Caps Lock bound as Compose, which lets you enter symbols not found on your keyboard layout. Not a modifier, to be clear, but Alt Gr is similar.

Comment: Meta is usually Alt. If your keyboard has a Windows key, that's Super.

Comment: Check out questions tagged [tag:shortcut-keys] for answers to some of your questions

Comment: Thank you for suggestions - I have added a more general question here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1160090/xmodmap-and-keyboard-shortcuts-how-does-the-system-work-19-04-xorg